# Adding dates with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I was trying a simple date calculation by adding a certain number of days to a datetime.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
initial = datetime.date(2019, 3, 5)
delta = relativedelta(day=60)
print(f"Initial date: {initial.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}")

new_dt = initial + delta
print(f"Final date: {new_dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}")
```

However my output is:

```
Initial date: 05-03-2019
Final date: 31-03-2019
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delta = relativedelta(day=60)
new_dt = initial + delta
```

The day of `initial` is set (not incremented but set) to 60 but since there are only 31 days in that month it is set to 31.

https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html

If your intention is to increment the date by 60 days use

```
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=60)
```

OR

```
delta = relativedelta(days=60)
```

instead of

```
delta = relativedelta(day=60)
```

Comment: Actually I could just have used `relativedelta(days=60)`, `days` instead of `day`. That was my mistake. Thanks for pointing me to the docs.

Comment: @JoelGMathew added it to the answer.